# How to make this if statement with multiple conditions shorter?

Tags: c#, .net

I began fixing a problem the customer had with signatures not displaying correctly. The customer has 2 columns one for current and for prior times - so they can have five outcomes:

```
Current new  These two we just need to show the CurrDate
Prior New      This hits the 1st ret

Current New    This hits the 3rd ret
Prior Null

Current old  These three we need to show the PrevDate
Prior old      This hits the 2nd ret

Current new    This hits the 2nd ret
Prior old

Current old    This hits the 4th ret
Prior null
```

I and got to this if statement

```
    private string CheckBoxDescription()
    {
        if (ViewState["PrevDate"] != null &&
            ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString().Trim() != "" && 
            ViewState["CurrDate"] != null && 
            ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString().Trim() != "")
        {
            if (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString()) > 
                   DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12") &&
                DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString()) >
                  DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12"))
            {
                return "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate;
            }
            else
            {
                return "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate;
            }
        }

        if (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString()) >
            DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12"))
        {
            return "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate (Same as the CurrDate above);
        }
        else
        {
            return "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate (Same as the PrevDate above);
        }
    }
```

I tried this:

```
    if (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString()) > 
          (DateTime.Parse("011-JAN-12")) &
       (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString()) > 
          (DateTime.Parse("011-JAN-12")) | 
       (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString()) !=
           null)))
```

but it will not pick up one of the null values.

Comment: I forget the syntax but with C# 6 and think there is a shortened null, value check.  What version?

Comment: You can use !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewState["PrevDate"]) as a single check to place the null check and the check for empty string using trim.

Comment: I would also store all of your `ViewState["Key"]` into it's own local variable so you do not have to query the `ViewState` every time you want to access the value.

Comment: Instead of writing code, can you describe your requirement using simple words? Your code is long and has too many branches. Some syntax/framework can reduce code length a little but never helps you write clean code.

Comment: As jamie note: repeatedly accing array element (as repeatedly casting and convering them) takes space and time. Using local variables is highly recommended!

Answer (score 3):

For the null/empty check you can use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewState["PrevDate"]) &&
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewState["CurrDate"]))
```

I would also store the parsed dates in variables rather than parsing each time

```
DateTime minDate  = new DateTime(2012,1,1);
DateTime prevDate = DateTime.Parse(ViewState["PrevDate"]));
DateTime currDate = DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"]));
```

then use those in the comparisons:

```
if (prevDate > minDate &&
    currDate > minDate)
```

For the last check, `DateTime.Parse` will *never* return null so I'm not sure what conditions you're trying to check there.  If the *string* value could be null then just check that:

```
if (currDate > minDate &
       (ViewState["PrevDate"] == null ||
        prevDate > minDate)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string CheckBoxDescription()
{
    if (ViewState["PrevDate"] != null &&
        ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString().Trim() != "" && 
        ViewState["CurrDate"] != null && 
        ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString().Trim() != "")
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString()) > 
               DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12") &&
            DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString()) >
              DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12"))
        {
            return "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate;
        }
            return "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate;
    }

    if (DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString()) >
        DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12"))
    {
        return "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate (Same as the CurrDate above);
    }
        return "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate (Same as the PrevDate above);
}
```

From what you have done in the second block of code this is was what i could change, not much but what i have done is removed the else statements as you are returning i the first if statement, the else isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend: Case statements https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/06tc147t.aspx

Multiple if statements also have a habit of slowing your code down because the IDE has to process all the conditions

With Case statements, it will only use certain pieces of information based on conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this considerably by writing a method to parse a string into a nullable date:

```
private static DateTime? parseDate(object date)
{
    DateTime result;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(date.ToString(), out result))
        return result;

    return null;
}
```

Note that I had to make the parameter an `object` because I don't know what type `ViewState["key"]` returns.

One you have that you can simplify your code. However, doing so reveals that you haven't handled the case where `currDate` is not a valid date:

```
private string CheckBoxDescription()
{
    var prevDate = parseDate(ViewState["PrevDate"]);
    var currDate = parseDate(ViewState["CurrDate"]);

    if (prevDate != null && currDate != null)
    {
        return 
            prevDate > DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12") && currDate > DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12") 
            ? "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate" 
            : "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate";
    }

    // You have a problem here. What if currDate is not a valid date?

    if (currDate == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Your current code doesn't handle this case.");

    if (currDate > DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12"))
    {
        return "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate (Same as the CurrDate above)";
    }
    else
    {
        return "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate (Same as the PrevDate above)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

```
private string CheckBoxDescription()
{
    var prevDate = ViewState["PrevDate"] != null && ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString().Trim() != ""
    ? DateTime.Parse(ViewState["PrevDate"].ToString()) 
    : null;
    var currDate = ViewState["PrevDate"] != null && ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString().Trim() != "" 
    ? DateTime.Parse(ViewState["CurrDate"].ToString()) 
    : null;

    if (prevDate != null && currDate != null)
    {

       return 
        prevDate > DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12") && currDate > DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12") 
        ? "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate" 
        : "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate";
    }

    if (currDate > DateTime.Parse("01-JAN-12"))
    {
        return "SELECT Statement to get CurrDate (Same as the CurrDate above);
    }
    else
    {
        return "SELECT Statement to get PrevDate (Same as the PrevDate above);
    }
}
```